# How to stop sling scheduler work if inconsistent situation occures inside the job?

Tags: java, aem, scheduler, sling

I have the following field:

```
@Reference
private Scheduler scheduler;
```

`Scheduler` from package `org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler`

And I have `Runnable` job field:

```
protected Runnable job;
```

I run scheduling:

```
scheduler.schedule(this.job, this.scheduleOptions);
```

I want to stop scheduling if inside the job occurs something wrong

```
public void run() {
       if(checkThatSomethingWrong()){
            //stop job
       }
}
```

Comment: Use `scheduler.unschedule(<<job name>>);`. The job Name should be the name that was set in the `scheduleOptions`. Refer this [Scheduler API](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/Scheduler.html#unschedule-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @rakhi4110 I don't know job name inside the Runnable

Comment: Use `this.scheduleOptions.name(<<job name>>)` to set a name to the job, before scheduling the job using the `scheduler.schedule(this.job, this.scheduleOptions);`. Later use the same name to cancel the job using `scheduler.unschedule(<<job name>>);`. Check the [ScheduleOptions API](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/ScheduleOptions.html#name-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @rakhi4110 I can repeat that I don't know job name inside the job!

Comment: You can give any name to the job. Its your wish. Any custom name to identify the job.

Comment: @rakhi4110 Yes, I can give any name. But I will know this name only inside the code where I will schedule the job rather than inside the job

Comment: @rakhi4110 I have different classes in different packages. **MyScheduler** where I wrote **sheduler.schedule(...)** and **public class MyJob implements Runnable{...}**